# Strange VB.Net performance issue on start up

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

My exe (vb project) when launched takes a minute to show the main form. On investigation, I found the below. It may appear unbelievable but it is happening. Even lot of googling didn't help.

Happens only in exe and not when run from Visual Studio.
Happens only in Released mode.
Happens on all machines. Already happening in production for all users.
Connecting to a different database does not make any difference(Not a data loading issue).
SQL Server profiler shows no activity for that one minute.

Logging revealed that the culprit seems to be the following line:

```vb
gfrmMain = New frmMain 'frmMain is a windows form
```

Further logging revealed that one minute delay happens before InitializeComponent() is called in frmMain constructor.

```vb
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    'Reached this line after a minute - what???
    InitializeComponent()
    ...
End Sub
```

Process monitor revealed that there was no registry, file system, network activity for the process. It just sits idle.

Things I have tried:

1. Unchecking optimisations for released mode
2. Removing "MyBase.New()" - did not make any difference

I am clueless what else to try?

Note: Solution is a mix of c# and vb projects. In fact main vb project and rest all c# projects. It started happening few months ago. All was fine until then (launched in few secs).

[image: VS Profiler results]

Comment: Attach debugger after start and look at callstacks... probably in mixed mode... Or use any profiler to investigate.

Comment: Did you try running it as Administrator or some account with higher privelige?

Comment: It runs fine when debugger is attached after start.Runs fine with VS profiler. Exe runs in admin mode as it is a prerequisite for this application.

Comment: Forgot to mention that during that 1 minute, memory usage increases from 20 MB to 1.3 GB and then drops again to 20 MB

Comment: Have you ever tried to change the project build sequence (if possible) and see if the current startup project takes time OR any possible startup project takes time ?

Comment: what components your form is loading in memory check it first by debugging InitializeComponent()

Comment: Didn't change build sequence and just reviewed and it looks as expected. This solution is a single startup project. I don't have any issue with any other solution or project taking time to run. Thanks for the ideas. Please keep them coming.

Comment: Apart from what others mentioned, take a look at what your antivirus software does when application starts. Real time scan features can sometime affect.

Comment: @JackGajanan - My form uses various controls and even some third party controls (DevExpress). I had put logging extensively in InitializeComponent() and realized that the "wait" happens even before it is called. InitilizeComponent() once called get executed in 1-2 sec.

Comment: Just tried disabling antivirus (McAfee) but same results. Thanks.

Comment: IMO, Since you are loading too much stuff at startup, either you should load few of them at a later time (if possible) or introduce a splash or loader screen that normally other apps (say for example Photoshop loads fonts and other stuffs) does.

Comment: I have had a situation in the past where the Release code hit a bug in the compiler. I could rebuild the project on a different machine and it would still hit the bug. The only work around I could find was to release the debug version to production without all of the pdb files.

Comment: is you project is taking time after MyBase.New() or before that cause if some of the components have shared or static thing project will init them first

Comment: What is you start form and where is this >> gfrmMain = New frmMain

Comment: @NeverHopless - That does not reduce the start up time. I am trying to find out what is causing the delay to eliminate it.

Comment: @David - This statement is in startup module file of the project.

Comment: @Jack - It is taking time before it hits the first line of InitializeComponent() method. It happens even if I remove that line (mybase.New()). VS profiler did indicated that time taken was inside CLR while initialzing form.

Comment: I would like to post a pic showing VS profiler results. Is it possible?

Comment: Would you mind explaining the reason for negative vote for the question???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. We found it is .NET 4.5.1. Our application is targeting .net 4.0, but recently 4.5.1 overwrites that. Suddenly one form out of 12 takes 60 seconds to load and uses 300 MB of memory. Try reloading the version of .NET that worked (v4.0 for us) and then stop the auto-update to 4.5.1 via Windows Update (hide the update) and let me know how you go. I also found that turning off Optimizations for Release mode worked - but I decided against going down this path.

Comment: You are correct. It works in 4.0. Unfortunately it won't be possible for us to uninstall and hide the update on every user's machine.

Also it works if I release in x86 mode. We probably will go this way as it will cause much less headache for us.

Comment: Accepting your answer as you had the most meaningful solution